# How to check all check boxes at a click of a button

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I am new to Swing, UI and MVC
I have created a code based on MVC. Now my problem is that that in the controller part i have an actioneventlistener which listens to different button clicks. Out of all those buttons i have "select all" and "de-select all". In my view i have a table, one of the column of that table contains "check boxes". Now, when i click the "select-all" button i want to check all the check boxes and with "de-select all" i want to uncheck all of them.

Below is my code which is not working. Please tell me what am i doing wrong here. Also, if someone knows a more elagent way please share. Thanks

In my view

```
public class CustomerSelectorDialogUI extends JFrame{

  public CustomerSelectorDialogUI(TestApplicationUI ownerView, DummyCustomerStore dCStore, boolean modality) {

    //super(ownerView, modality);
    setTitle("[=] Customer Selection Dialog [=]");
    //setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    custSelectPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    selectAllButton = new JButton(" Select All ");
    clearAllButton = new JButton(" Clear All ");
    applyButton = new JButton(" Apply ");
    cancelButton = new JButton(" Cancel ");

    PopulateAndShow(dCStore, Boolean.FALSE);
}

public void PopulateAndShow(DummyCustomerStore dCStore, Boolean select) {
    List data = new ArrayList();
    for (Customer customer : dCStore.getAllCustomers()) {
        Object record[] = new Object[COLUMN_COUNT];
        record[0] = (select == false) ?  Boolean.FALSE : Boolean.TRUE;
        record[1] = Integer.toString(customer.customerId);
        record[2] = customer.fullName;
        data.add(record);
    }
    tModel = new TableModel(data);

            // In the above for loop accoring to user input (i.e click on check all or
            // uncheck all) i have tried to update the data. As it can be seen that i
            // have a condition for record[0]. 
            //After the loop, here i have tried several options like validate(). repaint but to no avail

            customerTable = new JTable(tModel);
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(customerTable);

    setContentPane(this.createContentPane());

    setSize(480, 580);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);


}

private JPanel createContentPane() {
    custSelectPanel.setLayout(null);

    customerTable.setDragEnabled(false);
    customerTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

    scrollPane.setLocation(10, 10);
    scrollPane.setSize(450,450);

    custSelectPanel.add(scrollPane);

    buttonPanel.setLayout(null);
    buttonPanel.setLocation(10, 480);
    buttonPanel.setSize(450, 100);
    custSelectPanel.add(buttonPanel);

    selectAllButton.setLocation(0, 0);
    selectAllButton.setSize(100, 40);
    buttonPanel.add(selectAllButton);


    clearAllButton.setLocation(110, 0);
    clearAllButton.setSize(100, 40);
    buttonPanel.add(clearAllButton);

    applyButton.setLocation(240, 0);
    applyButton.setSize(100, 40);
    buttonPanel.add(applyButton);

    cancelButton.setLocation(350, 0);
    cancelButton.setSize(100, 40);
    buttonPanel.add(cancelButton);

    return custSelectPanel;
}
}
```

Table Model

```
private class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List data;
    public TableModel(List data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    private String[] columnNames = {"Selected ",
            "Customer Id ",
            "Customer Name "
    };

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return COLUMN_COUNT;
    }
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data == null ? 0 : data.size();
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object value, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        getRecord(rowIndex)[columnIndex] = value;
        super.fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
    }

    private Object[] getRecord(int rowIndex) {
        return (Object[]) data.get(rowIndex);
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return getRecord(rowIndex)[columnIndex];
    }

    public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        if (data == null || data.size() == 0) {
            return Object.class;
        }
        Object o = getValueAt(0, columnIndex);
        return o == null ? Object.class : o.getClass();
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        if (col > 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
} 
}
```

A Views Action Listener

```
class CustomerSelectorUIListener implements ActionListener{

CustomerSelectorDialogUI custSelectView;
Controller controller;

public CustomerSelectorUIListener (Controller controller, CustomerSelectorDialogUI custSelectView) {
    this.custSelectView = custSelectView;
    this.controller = controller;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String actionEvent = e.getActionCommand();

    else if ( actionEvent.equals( "clearAllButton" ) )
    {
        controller.checkButtonControl(false);
    }       
    else if ( actionEvent.equals( "selectAllButton" ) )
    {
        controller.checkButtonControl(true);
    }       
}
}
```

Main Controller

```
public class Controller implements ActionListener{

CustomerSelectorDialogUI selectUI;
DummyCustomerStore store;

public Controller( DummyCustomerStore store, TestApplicationUI appUI )
{
    this.store = store;
    this.appUI = appUI;
    appUI.ButtonListener( this );           
} 

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    String viewAction = event.getActionCommand();

    if (viewAction.equals("TEST")) {
        selectUI = new CustomerSelectorDialogUI(appUI, store, true);
        selectUI.showTextActionListeners(new CustomerSelectorUIListener( this, selectUI ) );
        selectUI.setVisible( true );
    }
}

public void checkButtonControl (Boolean checkAll) {
    selectUI.PopulateAndShow(store, checkAll);
}       
}
```

Comment: Please show the implementation of the table model.

Comment: Is `controller.checkButtonControl(true);` executed at all ? It is not clear/shown how you setup the controller.

Comment: Yes, it is. And when i click "select all" i can see in the debug that the record[0] values are all true and when i click "clear all" all the record[0] values become false

Comment: [crossposted](http://www.coderanch.com/t/596004/GUI/java/check-all-check-boxes-at)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue is related to the way you recreate the table once the button is clicked. You are creating a new table and adding it to a content pane. However the old controls also remain there. If you add:

```
getContentPane().removeAll();
```

Before calling:

```
setContentPane(this.createContentPane());
```

It should fix the immediate issue. However, you should consider using much more efficient way of updating the table - simply update the model or replace it. Removing the whole table is not necessary.

EDIT:

Here is a simplfied example how to update the model:

```
public void toggleSelection(Boolean select) {
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < tModel.getRowCount(); rowIndex++) {
        tModel.setValueAt(select, rowIndex, 0);
    }
}
```

Then, just execute this method from the controller.

You can also rebuild the model if necessary, ie (again, simplified):

```
public void toggleSelection(Boolean select) {
    List data = new ArrayList();

    for (int idx = 0; idx < 5; idx++){
        Object record[] = new Object[] {select, "test", "test"};
        data.add(record);
    }

    TableModel model = new TableModel(data);
    customerTable.setModel(model);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, worked! Thanks. Bytheway, can you explain a bit more (edit your answer) on how to do it more efficiently.

Comment: wow, i tried your first toggleSelection method and it worked without revalidate, repaint or getContentPane(). This looks soo clean, simplified and easy to understand now. 2 Thumbe Up :)

Comment: aaach I think you are complicated simple things, OP will returns here for rest of :-) btw +1

Answer (score 0):

adding `revalidate()` in `PopulateAndShow` may help

```
setSize(480, 580);
setResizable(false);
setVisible(true);
revalidate();
```

Comment: could you please post all the code so we can compile it and run ourselves?